# Fundamental solution of an operator.

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In textbook given such operator $\frac{d^2}{dx^2} -8\frac{d }{dx} + 15$ and solved without any explanation

Can someone give ideas how to solve it? Or any sources where it explained?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How to solve $\int_a^b$ ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_equation_(calculus)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let differential operator $op \mapsto \frac{d^2}{dx^2} -8\frac{d }{dx} + 15$

Apply $op$ to function $y(x)$:

$$op \cdot y(x) = y''(x)-8y'(x)+15y(x)=0$$

The characteristic equation $\lambda ^2-8 \lambda +15=0$
has the solution $\{\{\lambda \to 3\},\{\lambda \to 5\}\}$

and leads to the general solution of the ODE

$$y(x)\mapsto c_1 e^{3 x}+c_2 e^{5 x}$$